# One Page Scroll Plugin Pagination

Tags: jquery

I'm working with [One Page Scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) on a project, and I'm wondering if there's a way to change the pagination from dots to numeric pagination. So if there are six slides, the first slide shows "1/6" the second slide would be "2/6" and so on — I can't quite figure out what method I would use to figure out which section I'm on to display a number.

Comment: You can also take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) which is a much active and complete plugin, and then check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33101801/1081396).

Comment: I had a look at this plugin before I started using one page scroll, but I was having a lot of issues getting the horizontal scroll to work with either a mouse or a touch device.
Vertical scroll worked fine, but horizontal wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin doesn't seem to have too much options.

One thing you can do, is use jQuery to create text and place it inside the links, and tweak the CSS to make the "balls" disappear.

The example I ran directly on the demo page:

```
$('ul.onepage-pagination li a').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var li = elem.parent();
    var ul = li.parent();
    elem.html((li.index() + 1) + '/' + ul.children().length);
});
```

There you go, and there as your running through each link, you can remove or add css classes or styles, or just tweak the .css directly.

Comment: I think I'm missing something basic with this answer, I've added this script into the HTML of the page (both the demo and my project) and hidden the balls with CSS, but it doesn't seem to make any change. Any chance you could make a fiddle?

Comment: Ok, I just copied the ul HTML into the fiddle, and the same jQuery, and added a flag that you can change to disable, and see that it won't affect the ul, you can add li's if you wish. https://jsfiddle.net/bbcmzmky/

Comment: Can I have any custom-text like ``Slide1``, ``Slide2`` in pagination instead of slider counter.
Or can we get pagination automatically from ``data-index`` data from HTML?